# How to get feature count of a GeoJSON into a bash variable?

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, bash, ogrinfo, variables

I would like to have the number of features in a GeoJSON loaded into a `bash` variable. An example GeoJSON, `example.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

I use [ogrinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html), grep & awk to get the number of features:

```
featurecount="$(ogrinfo -so example.geojson example | grep 'Feature Count' - | awk '{print $3}')"
```

Check:

```
echo $featurecount # outputs: 3
```

This is a bit tedious though.

**How can I get the feature count integer of a GeoJSON into a variable in a simpler way?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
featurecount=$(jq '.features | length' example.geojson)
echo $featurecount
3
```